# Start and Office Communicator Chat from Python

Tags: python, ocs

Does anyone know how I can lunch Microsoft Office Communicator and start an Chat from a Python script?

Regards
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the Office Communicator COM API, referred to [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cmayo/archive/2009/01/08/the-office-communicator-automation-api-in-2-min.aspx).

About using COM in Python, I recommend using the win32com.client and pythoncom libraries. They are bundled in the ActiveState Python bundle but can be downloaded separately if you don't use AS. More about that [here](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html).